# Render has strange artifacts

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, normals

I've got a problem with my rendering! I'm trying to render some objects:

[image: 3D view]

But, this is how it renders:

[image: incorrect render]

Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 9):

Your object's normals are not in the right direction.

You have to select all your object one after one and do this :

<kbd>Tab</kbd> for edit mode, then go to the Tools panel on left of the 3d view (<kbd>t</kbd>)and click on Recalculate on the Normals pannel.

[image]
This will correct how your normals are directed and also in your case your render.

If you want to see the direction of your normals (which have to always go on the outside of your object) go on the UI panel on right of the 3d view (<kbd>n</kbd>) go to mesh display and select display face (or vertex) normals as line here:[image]

and little line are going to show you were your normals are pointing.

Last but not least : For a better render (a smooth shading of your object) you can add a smooth on the Tools pannel on left

[image]