# remapping left click in 3D view

Tags: 3d-view, customization, shortcut, 3d-cursor

I'm using Blender 2.73 with a 3 button mouse on Windows.

In the User Preferences I've changed the mapping for Set 3D Cursor from Action Mouse to <kbd>Alt</kbd> Action Mouse.  (Like many Blender newbies I keep accidentally left clicking.)

I can't find anywhere what the mappings are for various key and mouse combinations so I'm wondering if I'll regret this remapping in the future?

Comment: IMHO it's easier to learn blender using the standard configuration. Most tutorials and manuals presume you are using standard keys, once you modify things you are on your own...

Comment: Possible dupe of http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21169/how-do-i-find-out-what-tool-a-shortcut-is-triggering

Comment: @cegaton; no pain, no gain, eh?

Comment: @lumpynose whatever floats your boat :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can search for key combinations in Preferences->input  to see what it is used for

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I missed that about changing where it searched.  What's the difference between Action Mouse, Select Mouse, and Left Mouse; is that documented somewhere?  Are Action Mouse and Left Mouse the same if no preferences have been changed?  Likewise for Select Mouse and Right mouse?

Comment: @lumpynose Right and Left are obvious but you can choose one for SELECT and the other one will be ACTION