# What are the hotkeys used in this video in Blender 2.69.1?

Tags: modeling, mesh, shortcut

I'm watching a video which appears to be quite old: http://www.cgmeetup.net/home/uv-unwrapping-and-texture-painting-in-blender-tutorial/

What I need to know is what the hotkeys he's using do, and what are they mapped to now. Hotkeys such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>, and that's all I can think of right now.

When I tried using some of these hotkeys or pulling up a menu with one on the menu, they didn't seem to work. Perhaps they don't work with the current version of blender?

By the way: I am using Blender 2.72b. Internet connection where I am is slow ATM so I can't just download the latest.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/21169/599. The shortcuts *probably* haven't changed between then and now, but note that blender's shortcuts are context sensitive. They'll depend on what editor and what mode you're in. You may find this [interactive cheatsheet](http://waldobronchart.github.io/ShortcutMapper/#Blender) helpful.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> in object mode with an object selected you can apply the location, rotation, scale. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> in object mode with at least two objects selected will  join the objects to one object <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> in edit with some vertices or edges or faces selected mode gives a vertices menu <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> in edit mode with 4 edges selected fills it with a face (beauty fill).

The hotkeys are the same for version 2.62 and 2.75 so i guess they are the some for 2.72b

Comment: What you describe for Alt+F is what F does, Alt+F is Beauty Fill. Short explaination is : trying to fill selected with equal triangle faces

Comment: @bithur, thanks I'm going to change it in the answer.

Comment: I don't understand... in the video regarding ALT+F he fills in a bunch of edges with faces using ALT+F. Its not working for me. I assumed that it worked for more than four faces judging by the video but nothing is happening except a Checkbox with the text: "Beauty Fill" Appearing in the options under the panel pulled up by pressing "T" in edit mode...